# Order of Items in Plist

Tags: objective-c

I am using a Plist..but i want to retrive the items from Plist in its original order(not in sorted order).
How I will do this..??

Answer (score 1):

[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:]

Of course that only makes sense if the file was *written* in an ordered manner.